# QGIS - Link layer symbology based on column linked with another layer

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have 1 polyline layer and 1 polygon layer. They both have a column with the same values.

I want the polyline layer to have the same color of the polygon layer when the values are the same. I didn't find any function in the color properties of the polyline layer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to use Categorized symbology with the same value on both layer and then apply the same color ramp to each.

**The easy case** : the column with the same values on both layer is the one that you use to categorize the polygon. you juste have to use the Categorized renderer on your line layer using the same column then apply the same color ramp on both layer (or set color manualy if few categories)

**The harder case** : the column with the same values on both layer is NOT the one that you use to categorize the polygon. In that case you need to recover the value used to categorize the polygon and use them to categorise your line layer.
This could be done by using below expression rather than a field name for the value setting of the line layer categorized renderer.

```
attribute( get_feature( 'Polygon_layer_name',  'Name_of_the_column_with_same_value_in_POLYGON_layer' , attribute(@feature, 'Name_of_the_column_with_same_value_in_LINE_layer' )), 'Name_of_the_column_with_same_value_in_POLYGON_layer')
```

(Note that field name are used as parameter and so are between single quote rather than the usual double quote)

After entering the expression just click the Classify button and apply the same color to the line and polygon

As a side note if your line and polygon have the same color you wont be able to see the line on top of same color polygon so you may want to further alter your symbology to get something legible (below I used drop shadow but altering the the opacity or any other modification could give you acceptable result depending on your need)

[image]

Comment: No sure to understand : I think I'm in the first case (the column with the same values on both layer is the one that you use to categorize the polygon) but need the second solution (your script and result look like what I need) :)

I tested the second solution, the script is right but not giving me a result : attribute(get_feature( 'servelev_81f0e406_b6b4_4b68_9a32_74148d20b379',  'identifiantservelev',attribute(@feature, 'identifiantserviceelevation')),'identifiantservelev')

Comment: @Nelson What do you mean by "the script is right but not giving me a result" ? Did you update the classification by clicking on the "Classify" button ?

Comment: Also if you are in the first case (you use the 'identifiantservelev' field to symbolize the polygon) you just need to use the 'identifiantserviceelevation' field to symbolize the line and apply the same color ramp to both layer (dont use random color but an actual color ramp)

Comment: This script is right  "attribute( get_feature( 'Polygon_layer_name',  'Name_of_the_column_with_same_value_in_POLYGON_layer' , attribute(@feature, 'Name_of_the_column_with_same_value_in_LINE_layer' )), 'Name_of_the_column_with_same_value_in_POLYGON_layer')" so I tested it adapted to my data and the syntaxe was ok than I cliked on the classify button and it gave me only "other values" symbology. For the first case, the problem is, it will be too long to apply the symbology handly that's why I need the second solution.

Comment: I would like to show you my computer screens but I can't add any image in the comment.

Comment: Do you agree that the script takes the layer ID and not the layer name ? (servelev_81f0e406_b6b4_4b68_9a32_74148d20b379 instead of servelev)

Comment: I think I'm in the first case (the column with the same values on both layer is the one that you use to categorize the polygon) : I was wrong, I use another colum to categorize the polygons (RVB color code)

Comment: The expression should give you all the value, if you get only "other value" there are a problem (are you sure that both column are an exact match ? you can try a join to check for that). for the layer name or layer ID it should work with both. Lastly you can edit your question to add screenshot and all other precision...